# Microservice api gateway design

Tags: node.js, api, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I have some difficulties with the REST API design in microservices. 
All services is written in javascript.

Could you provide me what is best solution for api gateway which supports jwt authorization and websocket.

I have the following scenario:

1. Main frontend - react (dashboard, login)
2. main backend - nodejs
3. Service1 frontend - react
4. Service1 backend - nodejs
5. Service2 frontend - react
6. Service2 backend - nodejs

I am researching about KONG api gateway. I need to implemenent if user is logged in main front he can access to service1 and service2, if not logged redirect user to main frontend.

Answer (score 0):

For simple scenario you can develop own solution based for example on express and plugins (socket.io+jwt).
Other may be for your scenario will be nice GraphQL server like this https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/

Comment: which api gateway to use?

Answer (score 0):

if you use kong api gateway, you can solve the problem by using multiple authentication

if you use jwt authorization you can find anonymous field in jwt plugin settings

it can be solved in the following way

1. create anonymous consumer
2. fill the anonymous field in jwt configuration to consumer's id(like xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx) you made
3. apply jwt plugins to all services and routers
4. if you request without jwt token, you can find `HTTP_X_ANONYMOUS_CONSUMER=true` in request header meta
5. so you can check user or anonymous in all services

i think following link helps you
https://docs.konghq.com/0.14.x/auth/

Comment: Okay, i understand this. Thank you very much @fuzes. This answer is useful. 
Is it problem to use kong in docker-compose for development? How to dynamicaly configure routes and consumers. Is there any config file for that or ?

Comment: you can easily configure kong by using kong-dashboard. https://github.com/PGBI/kong-dashboard